# How to I set scrollTop position for new page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that always has the same menu on the left side of the page. When clicking on a href, the new page opens, but it scrolls back to the top of the page. I want the scrollTop position of the new page to be what it was in the previous page.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  event.preventDefault();
  var targetLink = $(this).attr('href'); 
  window.open(targetLink, '_self','top=scroll', 'top=500'); // top position dosent work for me, top position=scroll
});
```

How can I archive that?

Comment: append with `#ididtoscroll` in the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can't set scroll position if you are opening new page in the same window. If you open new page in new window then you can set scroll position as shown below :

```
var win = window.open(targetLink, '_blank',''); 
setTimeout(function(){win.scrollTo(0,scroll);},1000);
```

In case you are opening the page in same window, then below is the workaround for that :

```
var win = window.open(targetLink+"?scroll="+scroll, '_self','');
```

Here we have added scroll value at the end of link as query parameter, I hope you know about query parameter. Then on the second page we have to put below code in order to make it scroll.

```
var href = window.location.href;
var scrollPos = href.substring(href.indexOf("scroll")+7);
window.scrollTo(0,parseInt(scrollPos));
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, since it answers the question, I accept it. But It didn't really help me, because I occurred some other problems with scrolling. So I just used my div id for the position of the page, like href="/index/65#centerpage".

Comment: That is the more reliable way to do scrolling by passing id of the div on which you want to focus.

Answer (score 2):

You should include a querystring parameter in your redirect url that gives the top position that the new page should load

```
var targetLink = $(this).attr('href') + '&top=' + scroll;
```

Then on the next page that loads, use JS/jquery to set the top position to that value if it is detected in the querystring.

Comment: this will only set the new window's top position with respect to current one.
see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_open5